# Power Bi Slicer by Month rather Alphabetically

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have created a simple Dax showing the month of each date in my data, however when adding Slicer into Report Dashboard, it shows the months alphabetically rather than by month (Jan, Feb, Mar) Etc.

Do I need to add more to my Dax to tell Power Bi how I would like the result laid out?

```
Month = AW_Calendar_Lookup[Date].[Month]
```

Comment: Do you have a date table?

Comment: Everything is held in one table and I am creating a new column within that table then writing a formula (as above) to pull through the month of the date within the date column.

Comment: You need to create a date table and then you can put a sort on the month column.

Comment: I first tried to create a table within Excel, added months and sorted by date, which seemed to work. But when I loaded to Power BI, it converted to Text and wouldnt allow me to change. 
I then tried creating a table within Power BI, but again would only convert data type as Text and didnt let me change.
I must be doing something wrong as your solution doesnt work for me.

Comment: Follow the instructions to create a date table here: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/creating-a-simple-date-table-in-dax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort this how I wanted by using date column and selecting date hierarchy.
I think I just tried to be too smart with what I was trying.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a MonthNumber-like column in your table just go to Data pane, select Month column and choose `Sort by column` - MonthNumber in horizontal menu.

If you don't have such column, create another table, for example, using `Enter data` in horizontal menu:

| month | monthNumber |
| --- | --- |
| January | 1 |
| February | 2 |
| March | ... |

and create a relationship in Model pane between two Month columns.

Then make the same sorting as mentioned above within new table and use this table's Month column instead of original Month column in your visualizations.

Unfortunately, there is no other way to tell Power BI the sorting order for month names.